# Amazon S3 alters files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im uploading files through gateway to S3. 
My sample files containing two lines.

After uploading them, when i check that in s3 bucket, it merges both lines as single line. Which causes issue in further processing files.

Is it a known bug?

**Original file**

```
SiteCode:20167708, TankID:1, ATGWorking:Online, ProductLevelCurrent:2017.1, ProductVolumeCurrent:25026.36, WaterLevelCurrent:0, WaterVolume:0, ProductTemperatureCurrent:16
SiteCode:20167708, TankID:2, ATGWorking:Online, ProductLevelCurrent:2408.4, ProductVolumeCurrent:55930.52, WaterLevelCurrent:0, WaterVolume:0, ProductTemperatureCurrent:17
```

**File in s3**

```
SiteCode:20167708, TankID:1, ATGWorking:Online, ProductLevelCurrent:2017.1, ProductVolumeCurrent:25026.36, WaterLevelCurrent:0, WaterVolume:0, ProductTemperatureCurrent:16 SiteCode:20167708, TankID:2, ATGWorking:Online, ProductLevelCurrent:2408.4, ProductVolumeCurrent:55930.52, WaterLevelCurrent:0, WaterVolume:0, ProductTemperatureCurrent:17
```

Comment: S3 should not be changing your line endings.  Can you share the code you are using to read the file and upload to S3?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Im using curl script to upload files through AWS gateway. Files are in my local machine. My sample curl request is;  curl -X PUT  --header "x-amz-acl: public-read-write"  --header "x-amz-storage-class: STANDARD" -d@ATG.txt https://zzz/rathatest/ATG/customer1/p1.txt

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if you notice file in s3 it keeps a white space gap between two lines? (check the 2nd occurence of the SiteCode, that should be next line starting word)

Comment: @Ratha Have you tried with "\n" new line feed in ATG.txt file. Because I used new line feed in text file before storing to S3 bucket. It works for me!

Comment: @KumareshBabu I added "\n" at the end of very first line, and the file in s3 contains like "TankCapacity:33950 \n SiteCode:20167708".

Comment: @Ratha Can you add '+'. Sounds like "TankCapacity:33950" + "\n" + "SiteCode:20167708"

Comment: @KumareshBabu Did changes as you mentioned, Now my file in s3 looks like, PricePerLitre:105.953 + "\n" + SiteCode:20167708,  But Im not getting as two entries bcoz, I may need to change my java code? Currently i do like    bufferreader.readLine() from the incoming S3Event

Comment: @Ratha Yes. In Java code, after creating object for java.io.File Class. You add contents like "TankCapacity:33950" + "\n" + "SiteCode:20167708" and flush it. I too did in Java code for adding to File.